# USB HD that is R/W from Mac and Windows

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, usb, filesystem

If I have a USB external HD how can I format it so it is R/W from both Mac and Windows?
Is that possible?

Comment: @Lizzan: The question that was linked as duplicate is from 2011. Is the information still relevant after 8 years?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Same comment. That post is it still relevant? It was from 2011